# Authenticate WooCommerce REST API in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Okay so I'm VERRY VERRY VERRY new to the subject so please go easy on me. What I have done is to create a wordpress woocommerce website. What I want to do now is to get product-data from the wordpress site in node.js. If I have understood everything correctly i first have to Authenticate myself.

First i installed the WooCommerce package with:

```
npm install --save woocommerce-api
```

Then i tried to Authenticante like this:

```
    var WooCommerce = require('woocommerce');

var wooCommerce = new WooCommerce({
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  url: 'http://localhost/wordpress',


});
```

I realise It's an verry open question and i might be far of from on the right track. But I would appriciate some tips or guiding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you npm installed 'woocommerce-api', so you need to require that, not 'woocommerce'.

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
```

Refer to the documentation, but it looks like you instantiated mostly correctly. If you're using the WP REST API you'll need to include the keys wpAPI and version, as per the library's documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api

Now, if you want to get products, you would do something like this:

```
wooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result) {
  return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
});
```

Or you can use .get instead of .getAsync if you'd prefer to use callbacks over promises.

Comment: Thank you! However is there any way to make sure you Authenticated succssessfully? i don't get any error meassages but I dont manage to get products. I either get "Undefiend" or incorrect URL. If i surf up the URL it shows me all the json-data.

Comment: You should be able to add a .catch(function(e) { console.log(e) }) to the getAsync request. If any errors are throwing, you should be able to view them this way. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html